# Travis CI Triggering Multiple Builds on Push

Tags: git, github, travis-ci

I have a LaTeX Resume hosted [here](https://github.com/EvanOman/Resume) with Travis CI enabled in order to generate a new PDF on every push. You can find the Travis build info [here](https://travis-ci.org/EvanOman/Resume).

I have Travis set to build on push, however every push triggers two builds: one for the push and one for a tag -- even if there is no tag. You can see an example if this behavior below:

[image: Example double build]

I tried setting `on: tags` to false but this didn't change anything.

How can I set Travis to only build once for each push?

Here is my `.travis.yml`:

```
before_install:
- sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends texlive-fonts-recommended
  texlive-latex-extra texlive-fonts-extra texlive-latex-recommended dvipng
script:
- mkdir _build
- pdflatex -output-directory _build EvanOman.tex
deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key:
    secure: <HASHED KEY>
  file:
  - _build/EvanOman.pdf
  skip_cleanup: true
  detect_encoding: true
  on:
    tags: false
after_success:
  "curl --ftp-create-dirs -T _build/EvanOman.pdf -u $FTP_U:$FTP_P ftp://ftp.evanoman.com/public_html/EvanOman.pdf"
```

Comment: Try removing `deploy.on`, maybe?

Comment: It doesn't seem to have worked: https://ibin.co/2zrUsa6QYOwL.png

Comment: That's... intriguing. What's the project settings on Travis?

Comment: Do you mean [this page](http://pasteboard.co/k4QSdCTw3.png)? If I uncheck `Build pushes` no builds are triggered at all (tags or not)

Comment: This is really weird, did you try popping an question at the [TravisCI issue tracker](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci)?

Comment: I haven't yet, I figured my config was wrong. I will post and see what they say

Comment: Issue added: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6790

Comment: @набиячлэвэли I figured it out, it was my bad using an extra `deploy` block. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the error was using `deploy.provider: releases`.

What this does is trigger a deploy to the Github releases page for my repo. The problem was that if I pushed without a tag, Github would make a Draft release with an associated tag: `untagged:<commit hash>`. The addition of this new tag would then trigger another Travis build, thus the two builds for every push.

Since I am just posting the resulting PDF to my website via FTP, the solution is to remove the `deploy` block from my `.travis.yml`. Doing so removed the multiple builds per push and Travis is now behaving as I would like.

Here is my current `.travis.yml`:

```
before_install:
- sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends texlive-fonts-recommended
  texlive-latex-extra texlive-fonts-extra texlive-latex-recommended dvipng
script:
- mkdir _build
- pdflatex -output-directory _build EvanOman.tex
after_success:
  "curl --ftp-create-dirs -T _build/EvanOman.pdf -u $FTP_U:$FTP_P ftp://ftp.evanoman.com/public_html/EvanOman.pdf"
```